# insert using laravel 6 not working (function store) Array to string conversion

Tags: php, laravel

i tried to insert an annn but it gives me error `Array to string conversion`.knowing that all the fields are not obligatory plien, because the insertion is done according to the subcategory_id chosen in blade `edit`

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       
       $request->validate([  
        'category_id'=>['bail','required',],
        'souscategory_id'=>['bail','required',],
        'entreprise'     =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,1','required','string','min:2','max:255'],
        'domaine'     =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,1','required','string'],
        'contrat'     =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,1','required','string',],
        'niveaua'     =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,1','required','string'],
        'poste'     =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,2','required','string'],
        'marquem'   =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,7','required','string'],
        'marque'    =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,8','required','string'],
        'modele'    =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,8','required','string'],
        'annee'     =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,8','required','string'],
        'km'        =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,8','required','numeric'],
        'carburant'           =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,8','required','string','min:2','max:255'],
        'puissance'           =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,8','required','string','min:2','max:255'],
        'titre'          =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,1','required','string','min:2','max:255'],
        'description'    =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,1','required','string','min:30','max:255'],
        'prix'    =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,6','required','min:1','max:12'],
        'image'          =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,1','required','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg','max:2048'],
        'images.*'       =>['bail','exclude_unless:souscategory_id,1','required','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg','max:2048'], 
        //2 emploi/
        
     ]); 
       if($request->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $path = $request->image->store('annonces');
        $request->image = $path;
        }
        $request->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $Annonce = new Annonce($request->all());
        $Annonce->save();
        return Redirect::to("annonces")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

Comment: Do you already define all your fields into your model?

Comment: @SokChanty thx for u answer, yes i do `protected $fillable = [
      'category_id','souscategory_id','domaine','contrat','entreprise','niveaua','poste','salaire','marque','marqueem','modele','annee','km','carburant','poidsl','piece','autrepi','surface','chambre','salleb','faces','titre','description','image','images'
    ]; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create a new element from `$request` in Laravel you need to do it as below and assign each value of `$request` to the each attribute of `Announce` object:

```
$request->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

$Annonce = new Annonce();
$Annonce->user_id = $request->user_id;
$Annonce->some_column = $request->some_column;
$Account->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try by this:

```
use App\Models\Announce;
............................

$data = $request->all();

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

   $path = $request->image->store('annonces');
   $data['image'] = $path;
}

$data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

Announce::create($data);

return Redirect::to("annonces")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
```

**Make sure you imported the correct model namespace on your app.**

Answer (score 0):

although is not recommended to modify a request, you should do it in this way:

```
$request->request->add(['image' => $path, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id]);
```

or by

```
$request = array_merge($request->all(), ['image' => $path, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id]));
```

Comment: thx for u answer ,please write the complete syntax because I write like that but it doesn't work it gives me the same error `` if($request->hasFile(image))
       {
        $path = $request->image->store(annonces);
        $request->image = $path;
        }
        $request->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $request = array_merge($request->all(), [image => $path]);
        $Annonce = new Annonce($request);
        $Annonce->save();``

Comment: I've edited my answer to add  'user_id' variable. Sorry for not see it before.